# Box node sdk on Deno throws "Not implemented: crypto.Sign" error

Tags: deno, boxsdk

I want to use [Box Node SDK](https://github.com/box/box-node-sdk) on Deno (v1.30.3) . here is a simple example.

```
import BoxSDK from "npm:box-node-sdk@2.8.1";
import conf from "/path/to/config.json" assert {type: "json"};

const sdk = BoxSDK.getPreconfiguredInstance(conf);
const client = sdk.getAppAuthClient("enterprise");

client.users.get(client.CURRENT_USER_ID).then((me: any) => {
    console.log(me); // should print user’s name
})
```

This is what I get.

```
error: Uncaught Error: Not implemented: crypto.Sign
throw new Error(message);
^
at notImplemented (https://deno.land/std@0.177.0/node/_utils.ts:23:9)
at new Sign (https://deno.land/std@0.177.0/node/internal/crypto/sig.ts:45:5)
at Object.createSign (https://deno.land/std@0.177.0/node/crypto.ts:268:10)
at Object.sign (file:///Users/hkobayashi/Library/Caches/deno/npm/registry.npmjs.org/jwa/1.4.1/index.js:151:25)
at Object.jwsSign \[as sign\] (file:///Users/hkobayashi/Library/Caches/deno/npm/registry.npmjs.org/jws/3.2.2/lib/sign-stream.js:32:24)
at Object.module.exports \[as sign\] (file:///Users/hkobayashi/Library/Caches/deno/npm/registry.npmjs.org/jsonwebtoken/8.5.1/sign.js:204:16)
at TokenManager.getTokensJWTGrant (file:///Users/hkobayashi/Library/Caches/deno/npm/registry.npmjs.org/box-node-sdk/2.8.1/lib/token-manager.js:286:48)
at AppAuthSession.\_refreshAppAuthAccessToken (file:///Users/hkobayashi/Library/Caches/deno/npm/registry.npmjs.org/box-node-sdk/2.8.1/lib/sessions/app-auth-session.js:79:18)
at AppAuthSession.getAccessToken (file:///Users/hkobayashi/Library/Caches/deno/npm/registry.npmjs.org/box-node-sdk/2.8.1/lib/sessions/app-auth-session.js:124:25)
at BoxClient.\_makeRequest (file:///Users/hkobayashi/Library/Caches/deno/npm/registry.npmjs.org/box-node-sdk/2.8.1/lib/box-client.js:300:18)
at BoxClient.get (file:///Users/hkobayashi/Library/Caches/deno/npm/registry.npmjs.org/box-node-sdk/2.8.1/lib/box-client.js:452:21)
at wrappedClientMethod (file:///Users/hkobayashi/Library/Caches/deno/npm/registry.npmjs.org/box-node-sdk/2.8.1/lib/box-client.js:589:30)
at Users.get (file:///Users/hkobayashi/Library/Caches/deno/npm/registry.npmjs.org/box-node-sdk/2.8.1/lib/managers/users.js:42:67)
at file:///Users/hkobayashi/dev/poc/poc24-deno/2023-02/box-hello.ts:8:14
```

Does this mean deno's crypto library hasn't yet fully implemented?
is there any workaround?

Comment: The example above is Server Auth with JWT, but running [Client Credentials Grant Authentication](https://github.com/box/box-node-sdk/blob/main/docs/authentication.md#client-credentials-grant-authentication) with the --unstable flag worked.